# How to add these data to my temporary table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want these retrieved data(two rows) insert into another(temporary) table called presubcategory. But in that table only one row is inserted. What's wrong in this code?

```
<?php
    require 'configuration.php';?>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $sql_c = "SELECT c.catId, s.subCatId, s.subCatName
              FROM category c, subcategory s
              WHERE c.catId=s.catId AND c.catId='".$_POST['action']."' ;";

    $result_c = $conn->query($sql_c);
    if($result_c->num_rows>0) {
        while($row = $result_c->fetch_assoc()) {
            $ctId    = $row['catId'];
            $sctId   = $row['subCatId'];
            $sctname = $row['subCatName'];

            $sql_d = "INSERT INTO presubcategory
            (presubcatId,precatId,presubcatName)
            VALUES('".$ctId."','".$sctId."','".$sctname."');";
        $conn->query($sql_d);          
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can do that in one query: `INSERT INTO table (columns) SELECT ....`

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Any references where I can learn more about injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As aynber pointed out, you can do this using an [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) statement:

```
<?php
require 'configuration.php';

if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO presubcategory
            (presubcatId,precatId,presubcatName)
            (
              SELECT c.catId, s.subCatId, s.subCatName
              FROM category c, subcategory s
              WHERE c.catId=s.catId
              AND c.catId='".$_POST['action']."' 
            );";
    $conn->query($sql);          
}
?>
```

This is untested, but I think it should do the trick, assuming that your select statement was already working properly.

Comment: Yes, this single SQL statement should be much faster than issuing multiple ones.

Comment: Yes, but that still has the extremely dangerous `$_POST` being injected into the query.

Comment: The whole idea of a database is "store the data once". Doing a ```INSERT FROM SELECT ...``` defeats that. When the underlying tables change you have to delete all the rows from your new copy table and re-run your ```INSERT```. That's OK for ten rows, it doesn't scale well for 1,000,000 rows.

Answer (score 2):

This is where you should create a view which includes the two original tables and the simple join.

```
CREATE VIEW presubcategory AS 
  SELECT c.catId, s.subCatId, s.subCatName
   FROM category c, subcategory s
   WHERE c.catId=s.catId';

SELECT `subCatId` as preSubCatId,
 `catId` as preCatId,
 `subCatName` as preSubCatName
 FROM presubcategory WHERE catid=?;
```

No copying of data needed and it satisfies the query you need against the preSubCategory table.